# What is the functional structure of "My friend is a brilliant student"?

Tags: determiners, structure

> My friend is a brilliant student.

Here which will be the functional structure?

1. Subject+predicator+complement.
   Or
2. **Determiner**+subject+predictor+**determiner**+complement.

If neither of these, please give me the right one.

Comment: Please edit your question to replace the word 'object' with the word complement. The noun phrase "a brilliant student" is not object of "is" bur predicative complement. Obligatory items are always complements.

Comment: Why are you saying functional?

Comment: You're asking about Parts Of Speech, and [how to parse a sentence](https://www.thoughtco.com/parsing-grammar-term-1691583#:~:text=When%20parsing%20a%20sentence%2C%20the,future%20tense%2C%20etc.).).

Answer (score 1):

> *My friend is a brilliant student.*

At immediate constituent level the functions are: subject *my friend* + predicate *is a brilliant student*.

At the next level down, the subject consists of determiner *my* + head *friend*. The predicate consists of predicator *is* + predicative complement *a brilliant student*.

The predicative complement consists of determiner *a* + modifier *briliant* + head *student*.

Note that there is no object.

Comment: Ooh sorry there was a mistake... but what about the subject? As determiner is a function like subjects.. then why can't we form like **determiner+subject**?

Comment: No: the subject consists of determiner+head. Thus the determiner is part of the subject consisting of determiner "my" + the head "friend".

Comment: Then the determiner is a grammatical catergory, not function?

Comment: No: determiner **is** a function. In _my friend_ the grammatical category of "my" is noun (pronoun), and the grammatical category of "friend" is noun. I said this in my answer.

Comment: Then Which are determiners and which are modifiers of determinative?

Comment: There is no determinative in your example, so there is no modifier in the subject. _My_ is a personal pronoun, and quantifiers like _all, some, few, some_ etc. are determinatives.

Comment: Also, note that 'determin**ative**' is a category term while determin**er** is a function term.

Comment: So, If I say, **some friends are present here**. **some friends** equals to **determiner+subject**. Is it okay now?

Comment: No: the subject is _some friends_, not just _friends_. Some friends is determiner+head.

Comment: @Salimuddin I've added a simplified tree diagram, which may help.

Comment: Why is it determinr+head. As determiner and subject are functions?   [[Sorry for bothering you asking so many questions!!]]

Comment: Determiner+head form the subject. Look at the tree diagram.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Function label abbreviations: D = determ**iner** / Comp = complement

Category label abbreviations:

NP = noun phrase / VP = verb phrase / Det = determin**ative** / N = noun / NP = noun phrase / Adj = adjective

Comment: So here head and determiner are functions and noun and determinative are catergories...?

Comment: @Salimuddin Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The determiners are part of the subject and the object. So for example if the object is "a brilliant student", that object is then made up of the article "a", the adjective "brilliant", and the noun "student".

When we're diagramming a sentence, we don't break determiners out as separate from the subject and object.

Note that in this case, there isn't an "object". There is a subject, a verb, and a predicate nominative. That wasn't your question but.

Comment: In the OP's example, the NP "a brilliant student" is not object, but predicative **complement** of "is".

Comment: I was taught it was a "predicative nominative". Maybe I should have explained that, but that wasn't what the question asked. But yes, I'd describe this sentence as "subject - verb - predicate nominative.

Comment: You should get rid of the word 'object' in your answer, since there is no object in the OP's example. The OP used the word 'object' in error. The NP "a brilliant student" is a predicative complement (your predicate nominative).

Comment: @BillJ Are predicative complements two types: 1. Subject complement, 2. Object complement. ??

Comment: @Salimuddin Yes, they are. In your example, it's a subject complement. But in, for example, _They elected Ed president_ , "Ed" is object and "president" is object complement.

Comment: @BillJ Okay,,,and many many thanks to you for your help...